# Cordova: Device Ready doesn't show

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, phaser-framework

I made a cordova project and device ready worked, I didn't get any errors.
Then I tried to add two javascript files and a folder full of images.  I have linked them in the index.html and didn't delete anything.. Now Device Ready does fire?
Note: I am using Xcode and developing a game for iOS and Android.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Badger Hop</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phaser.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

One Javascript file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/QmpCUSA5 (main.js). The other file is Phaser.Min.js (found here: https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/master/build/phaser.min.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.. I renamed the project after I put all those files in, turns out you can't do this.  I changed the name back to what it was before and now it works!

Answer (score 2):

In your `main.js` file I can't find any `deviceready` event handler.

Your app should wait this event before using any cordova function. You should wrap your app initializing function with a code like this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    console.log("Start App");
    // call your app init function
}
```

For a more clear example see the [Cordova hello world app](https://github.com/apache/cordova-app-hello-world/blob/master/www/js/index.js).

Does your `js/index.js` contains this code? Check it.

Comment: My app uses Phaser, which automatically starts when the device ready is called, it works well with Cordova. Thanks for the suggestion though!